# Wordpress "Publishpress Permission" : wp_query not finding all records for posts

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm a little bit confused with WP plugin (free) PublishPress Permissions ...

with the following code :

```
$args = array(
                'post_status' => '',
                'post_type' => 'post', // Adjust post type if needed
                'posts_per_page' => -1, // -1 retrieves all posts, you can set a specific number
                'author' => 2,
            );
            echo("avant query<br>");
            $query = new WP_Query($args);
            
            if ($query->have_posts())
            {
                echo("if<br>");
                echo("Nbre : ".$query->post_count."<br>");
                
            } else {
                    echo("else....");
                // No pending posts found
            }
```

...
I get different results depending if the plugin is activated (wrong result) or deactivated (correct result) ... with user's role as "editor" for 'pending' (wait for publish) posts.

Role as "Admin" give correct result.

I guess I'm missing something, but what ?

If "Permission", I can't find any valuable option/configruation.

Comment: Querying is heavily augmented in PublishPress depending on the current user. It's a powerhouse of custom permission logic, etc. that needs to be configured properly.

Comment: Ok, i understand... User #2 has 2 posts pending. Why Query returns only 1 ? Any direction to investigate ?